# Varien_Profiler and _redirect in Adminhtml

Tags: adminhtml, layout, redirect, profiler

I want to profile a particular slow admin action that we have, but it calls `_redirect` at the end, is there an in-built way of seeing this profile information, or will I have to manually create an event to listen to something like `controller_front_send_response_after` and output the information into a log file?

Incidentally, `Mage::run` calls `Varien_Profiler::stop('mage');` seemingly as the last thing the application does. Surely this call actually does nothing because the block is already rendered at that point, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post might help you: http://forrst.com/posts/Log_Varien_Profiler_output_to_file-h97.
It explains how you output the Varien_Profiler contents to a log.

With that you can create your own extension, create an observer that listens to `controller_front_send_response_after` (or any other event) and log the Profiler results in the observer.

Comment: This is essentially what I've done, with the exception I'm checking for a registry entry so that I only get output for the actions I want by registering that variable in the actions I wish to debug. I'll accept this answer if nobody comes up with a built in way of doing it (which I doubt they will).

Comment: I've actually looked for it before on Mage 1.7. wasn't in there yet :)