# Output profiler manually

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, action, profiler

Unfortunately, the profiler is not outputting data on my own controller actions, but those (including how magento comes to execute this action) I would like to profile.

Is there a code I can run in the end of my action to output the collected profiler data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution via that answer: [Varien_Profiler and _redirect in Adminhtml](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10250/varien-profiler-and-redirect-in-adminhtml#answer-10265)

Since the link didn't work anymore, I used archive.org's wayback machine.

Here the code:

```
    $timers = Varien_Profiler::getTimers();
    echo("<pre>");
    $out = "\n";
    foreach ($timers as $name=>$timer) {
        $sum = Varien_Profiler::fetch($name,'sum');
        $count = Varien_Profiler::fetch($name,'count');
        $realmem = Varien_Profiler::fetch($name,'realmem');
        $emalloc = Varien_Profiler::fetch($name,'emalloc');
        if ($sum<.0010 && $count<10 && $emalloc<10000) {
            continue;
        }
        $out .= number_format($sum,4)."\t".$count."\t".$name."\n";
    }
    echo($out);
    echo("</pre>");
```